# Printer ignores G29 command

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, bed-leveling, firmware

I have a 3D printer Ender 3 V2. I bought a BLTouch sensor for it and compiled my own Marlin firmware.

Now, my print run of the part is like this:

1. I heat up the table
2. Starting table calibration
3. After the calibration is completed, I click save to the EEPROM.
4. I start printing by selecting a file.

At this point, all printing is fine, but I would like to reduce the number of steps. Selected the print file and left. The printer heats itself, calibrates itself and then starts printing.
I tried turning on `RESTORE_LEVELING_AFTER_G28` and `ENABLE_LEVELING_AFTER_G28` separately in the firmware. The compiler won't let me turn them on together.

And to use such a G-code:

```
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G28 ; Home all axes
G29 ; Bed Leveling
G28 ; Home all axes
M420 S1 : Load Saved Mesh
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up a little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X0.1 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to start position
G1 X0.1 Y200.0 Z0.3 F1500.0 E15 ; Draw the first line
G1 X0.4 Y200.0 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to side a little
G1 X0.4 Y20 Z0.3 F1500.0 E30 ; Draw the second line
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up a little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X5 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move over to prevent blob squish
```

The printer simply ignores the `G29` command and **starts printing without calibration**. What can be the problem?

Comment: @0scar I still do not understand the difference between RESTORE_LEVELING_AFTER_G28 and ENABLE_LEVELING_AFTER_G28. I have read many websites, but I don't get it. Can you explain it briefly? Thank you!

Comment: `RESTORE_...` restores the prior state before `G28` (this can be enabled or disabled!), `ENABLE_...` will enable the leveling no matter what the previous state before `G28` was. Personally I use `ENABLE_...`. You need to fix your start G-code and use it accordingly to the firmware settings. E.g. is `ENABLE_...` is set, you don't need `M420...`

Comment: @0scar it didn't work

Comment: If you "print" a file only containing `G29` does that work?

Comment: @0scar I tried it, it doesn't work

Comment: Then you have a configuration error and as such not using leveling.